How to use SignalR Hub in class library project
How to use Signalr Hub class in class library project?
I do not see possible reference to Hub.
In application project (class library) I do not have access to this class

In Web project which is referencing application project I have access to the Hub

How to have access to it in Application project?

Application csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Bidnest.Persistance\Bidnest.Persistance.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


I'd consider building your own Interface in Bidnest.Application for the functionality that the SignalR hub provides. This means it doesn't need the actual SignalR library. You can then implement it as a dependency in your Bidnest.App and inject it. I can write you an answer to demo if you're not sure.

@AndrewB Alright so create some kind of abstraction for it? Sounds good I think you can write the answer. I would be very happy!

Hi @Pentium3k Could you kindly check the answer below ? Thanks.

Hi @Pentium3k - my bad, I thought you were just wanting to use a SignalR client library. If you're building an actual SignalR hub, then has a good answer below :-)

If we need to define signalr hub in Class Library (.net core) project, we have to install  Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core package. And I know it was deprecated.
As we know, the asp.net Core SignalR Package is already integrated into the asp.net Core 7/8 Web Application by default.
So if we want to use it in Class Library, we have to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core  manually.
I have written a repo before, here it the link you can refer https://github.com/Jason446620/AspNetCore7.

